# if convex or nonconvex function

Tags: convex-analysis

[image]

There is an iteration recurrence relations between the argument. In fact, it is part of my optimization model . The equation F is convex or not convex? thank u

Comment: The Y(t) is depend on the Y(t-1). But it is a linear realtion ship, such as Y(t)=a*Y(t-1). They are the same for W and Z

Comment: Looks like $F(x,y,z,w) = 2 X_{t-1}^{\square}$. And I don't understand how $x,y,z,w$ and $X,..$ play together.

Comment: if F(x,y)=x*y?it convex or non-convex?